# How do I rename the values in my column as I have misspelt them and cant rename them in R or Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I have a data frame that was given to me. Under the column titled state, there are two components with the same name but with different case sensitivities ie one is "London" and the other is "LONDON". How would i be able to rename "LONDON" to become "London" in order to total them up together and not separately. reminder, I am trying to change the name of the input not the name of the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, df is your current dataframe, in which you want to substitute "LONDON" for "London"

```
df <- data.frame(Country = c("US", "UK", "Germany", "Brazil","US", "Brazil", "UK", "Germany"),
                 State = c("NY", "London", "Bavaria", "SP", "CA", "RJ", "LONDON", "Berlin"),
                 Candidate = c(1:8))
```

```
print(df)
```

output

```
  Country   State Candidate
1      US      NY         1
2      UK  London         2
3 Germany Bavaria         3
4  Brazil      SP         4
5      US      CA         5
6  Brazil      RJ         6
7      UK  LONDON         7
8 Germany  Berlin         8
```

then run the following code to substitute London to all the instances where State is equal to "LONDON"

```
df[df$State == "LONDON", "State"] <- "London"
```

Now the output will be as

```
 Country   State Candidate
1      US      NY         1
2      UK  London         2
3 Germany Bavaria         3
4  Brazil      SP         4
5      US      CA         5
6  Brazil      RJ         6
7      UK  London         7
8 Germany  Berlin         8
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using the case_when function. I would do something like this:

´´´´

> mutate(data, State_def=case_when(State=="LONDON" ~ "London",
> State=="London" ~ "London",
> TRUE ~ NA_real_)

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand, but I think it should be as simple as this:

```r
x$state <- sub( "LONDON", "London", x$state, fixed=TRUE )
```

This should change LONDON to London